# How to access a specific column in the result set of a cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm creating a cursor to collect a set of rows that I want to delete in a table. But I also want to delete records in related tables that key off the table. Is it possible to get the field in a single column of a cursor so that I can use that value to delete the fields in the other tables as well (The field isn't explicitly defined as a foreign key in the other tables)

Comment: First of all. Why you're using a `CURSOR` in the first place? Please share some sample data and desired results as _formatted text not images_ with your attempt.

Comment: I also wonder why it isn't defined as a foreign key in the first place. Any possibility to set that up? If so, Cascade Deletes would help in this case, I believe.

Comment: @TinyHaitian That's an architecture thing that I have to work around.

Comment: @Sami The idea is that i have a table that I'm trying to filter out a set of rows to delete. I could use a temporary table to get just the ids that I want to delete and use that as a reference but that doesn't scale well.

Comment: Are you using a cursor because you want to delete the children and then the parent and then move on to the next row where you delete the children and then the parent and then repeat . . .  ??  If so, we are trying to recommend that you first delete the entire set of children once and then delete the entire set of parents.  But perhaps I just don't understand why you feel you need the cursor.

Comment: I want the cursor because I want a reference to the set of entries in the parent table that I want to delete, that ideally I can pick additional properties off of

Comment: I think that's why you would use a temp table or table variable.  A cursor goes row-by-row and it doesn't somehow keep the rows intact somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with Sami's comment; people tend to go to cursors because they think in a row-by-row processing mode, but SQLServer is totally focused on operating on things as a set. Consider building a temp table of all the rows you want to delete, then run delete operations that use that temp table as a driver for which rows in which other tables need deleting. If you can't use cascading deletes from FKs you need to engage in joining and delete in order from child up to parent

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE #delusers (userid INT);
INSERT INTO #delusers VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO #delusers VALUES(2);
INSERT INTO #delusers VALUES(3);

--For relationships: 
--  User.ID--hasmany-->Order.UserID and 
--  Order.ID--hasmany-->OrderProduct.OrderID

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM OrderProducts WHERE OrderID IN (SELECT o.id FROM orders o INNER JOIN #delusers u on o.userid = u.userid);
DELETE FROM Orders WHERE UserID IN (SELECT userid from #delusers);
DELETE FROM Users WHERE UserID IN (SELECT userid from #delusers);
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Here I've used a temp table as an example, but it's as easy to use a table var or even the original table just with a where clause if you feel the need. I've also used IN as it's the easiest way to deliver a readable demo of the overall point; you may choose some different method of coordination

Example 2:

```
--delete all orders and products on those orders from people with last name smith 

--For relationships: 
--  User.ID--hasmany-->Order.UserID and 
--  Order.ID--hasmany-->OrderProduct.OrderID

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM OrderProducts WHERE OrderID IN (SELECT o.id FROM orders o INNER JOIN users u on o.userid = u.userid WHERE u.lastname = 'smith');
DELETE FROM Orders WHERE UserID IN (SELECT userid from users WHERE u.lastname = 'smith');
DELETE FROM Users WHERE lastname = 'smith';
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: But if I know what rows I have to delete in the original table, why put that set into a temporary table when I can operate on it directly? I wanted to use a cursor so that I have the set of the rows that I want to delete, and I can just grab the id out of each row to know which rows in the child tables i have to delete, before deleting the cursor row.

Comment: *but it's as easy to use a table var **or even the original table just with a where clause** if you feel the need* - i'll add an example

Comment: The issue that I was having was that the query to determine the set of rows to delete in the original table has a lot joins in it. Before I delete the rows in the parent I would need to remove the rows in the child

Comment: If it has a lot of joins, feel free to simplify your life with `CREATE TABLE  #delusers AS SELECT query-with-a-lot-of-joins... DELETE FROM x WHERE userid IN (....)` etc

Comment: I typically use a table variable with just the primary key of the table you want to delete from.  You would then delete all the children based on the table of primary keys and then delete from the parent table.  The reason to store it in a table is to avoid missing children if the parent table is modified after deleting the children but before deleting the parent.

Comment: After retrieving the set, to delete in the original table I'd need to query off of the id in the temp table right? I couldn't delete from the temp table and have that delete the record in the parent table?

Comment: I think you're asking "if I delete from the temp table [rows] will it delete the original row from the original query that was used to generate the temp table data" -> no. The temp table data is nothing to do with the original rows of data, it just looks the same. What you're thinking is what a VIEW would do if views could have their rows deleted

Comment: @avery_larry hence the use of a transaction?

Comment: @CaiusJard Is there a means by which I can store the row data i'm interested in working on in a separate data structure, in such a way that it's a pointer to the original table where the data came from?

Comment: I'm curious; to what end?

Comment: Sorry I'm a relative beginner in sql so apologies for all of these questions. For the parent table If I can query for the set of rows that I want to delete, I can pick off the id for a given row and delete the required child entries, and then remove the entries in the parent row

Comment: You aren't really making much sense, sorry - this is probably driven by a lack of understanding of the process; I'm trying to say that if you have a query that identifies 1000 parents that must be delete and each parent has 20 children, and each of those children has 5 children, then we prepare a set of 3 queries that a) delete 100,000 grandchildren then 2) delete 20,000 children then 3) delete 1000 parents. "remove entries from parent row" - sentence doesn't make sense; rows are removed from tables and whatever an "entry" is, it cannot be removed from a row,unless you mean set a column null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200319/discussion-between-pingofdoom-and-caius-jard).